# Match() AGAINST() in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, match, mysql-workbench, against

I am running the following query to search for strings containing '838' in the full_address column.

I am using Match, Against in MYSQl,

I am running following Query,

```
SELECT * 
FROM fulladdress 
WHERE MATCH (full_address) AGAINST ('838*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Which is resulting only records starting with 838,
I want records ending with 838 and containing 838 in middle too.
What am I supposed to change?
I don't want to use 'LIKE'

I tried '*838', '%838%', '*838*' and others too. But, They didn't work.

Comment: Why don't you want to use LIKE?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM fulladdress WHERE full_address REGEXP '838'
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of what you have done not only for the OP, but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Rather than this the recommended `LIKE '838'` will simply do.